# Joomla - call function model within the model

Tags: joomla, model, private-functions

In a public function of my model I call

```
$user_type=$this->get_user_type();
```

In the same model I have

```
private function get_user_type()
{
    $user_type='asd';
    $asd_groups = (int)$config->get('asd_groups');
    $ver_groups = (int)$config->get('ver_groups');

    jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
    $user_groups=JUserHelper::getUserGroups($user->id);
    if(in_array($asd_groups,$user_groups)){
        $user_type='asd';
    }

    if(in_array($ver_groups,$user_groups)){
        $user_type='ver';
    }

    return $user_type;
}
```

The site give me a white page, if I comment the calling line "$this->get_user_type();" then it works...
I really don't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information or code here to help you… for example where is `$config` coming from and what is it? What version of Joomla is this on?

If `$config` is not defined as a `global` then that may be the source of the problem depending on your PHP setup.

Things you can do to help yourself find the problem, in Joomla's Global Configuration.

1. Set Error Messages to "Development" in Joomla (you are using a development site and not a live website right?)
2. Turn on Joomla's DEBUG mode

Then update your question with details of error messages, Joomla version and where this code is running (you say your model) and where `$config` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sure!
I have missed the two configuration variable when i moved the code from inside a function in a dedicated function.

I copied these two lines on the first row of the function and now it works!

```
$config = JComponentHelper::getParams(S_APP_NAME);
$user = JFactory::getUser ();
```